# Deploy the web application using weblogic adaptor for eclipse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I have installed weblogic 9.2 adaptor for eclipse kepler and try to deploy the application with eclipse. I right click the project and choose run configuration and click on run.

The server already started and i can see in the console,

But in the eclipse server tab it shows as `BEA WebLogic Server v9.2 at localhost [proj] [Stopped, Unable to validate weblogic domain].`

Any way But the server seems started as when i try to strat the server directly it says server already started.

But the problem is the application is not deployed when i use the plugin.

Also i want to clarify previously when i manually deploy i ran an ant build script which create a EAR file and then i deploy it using web logic web admin console. But now when i use eclipse does eclipse plugin do the build script job of creating a EAR and deploy it or is there i need to do more?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the weblogic plugin, but if you right click on the server, do you have the option to add/remove projects?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is eclipse is working on java 6 and weblogic is running on java 5.

The workaround is

add

-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true

after -vmargs string in eclipse.ini in your eclipse directory.